# Empty http response in "responsetxt" with status 200

Tags: asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

Below code in my `request.asp` page:

```
<%
    url= "http://mydomainname.com/test.asp"
    dim http, pxml, http_response
    set http = createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    http.open "GET", url, 0
    http.setrequestheader "content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    http.send ""
    response.write http.status
    response.write http.responseText
%>
```

this is the code in `test.asp` page:

```
<%
    response.write "<response>test page<response>"
%>
```

In the output `http.status` is 200 but `http.responseText` is empty why?

Comment: Should work fine. Try maybe changing to `Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")` as without "Server" it might cause some weird problems.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading something on microsoft.com that if the page returned (in your case test.asp) doesn't have the right content-type, responseText and responseXML are empty. The content-type should be either "text/xml" or "application/xml".

You can see what headers were send back by adding

```
Response.Write Replace(http.getAllResponseHeaders(), Chr(13) & Chr(10), "<br />")
```

to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The first line that should be written in test.asp is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

The first line in request.asp should be:

```
<%response.ContentType="text/xml"%>
```

Also, do a *view source* of request.asp, doing so you may see the xml tree